# HTML and CSS Navigation image hovering and Main content appearing underneath bar

Tags: html, css, alignment, navbar, display

**Code:** https://hastebin.com/otemiveduh.xml

**Problem Description:** There are two problems being that when another element, such as p-tag, is added underneath the section for the navigation bar. It'll be hidden underneath the navigation bar. In addition, the second error is that when highlighting over the image it doesn't change the background-colour of the whole entire height and if I change any of the other code in different sections, it ruins the vertical aligning of the image. I've been stuck with this error(s) for awhile and have to turn to the community for aid.

```html
<HTML>

<Head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    div.Header {}
    
    div.Navigation {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      list-style: none;
      line-height: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #001a33;
      position: absolute;
      overflow: hidden;
      z-index: 2;
      flex-direction: row;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-around;
      box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
    }
    
    div.Navigation>a {
      display: block;
      flex-grow: 1;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    div.Navigation a img {
      height: 22.1;
      width: 44;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    div.Navigation a:visited,
    div.Navigation a:active,
    div.Navigation a:link {
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    div.separator {
      margin-left: 60%;
    }
    
    div.Navigation a:hover {
      background-color: #000d1a;
    }
  </style>
</Head>

<Body>
  <div class="Header">
    <div class="Navigation">
      <a href="#"><img src="icons/home-button.png" /></a>
      <a href="#">Ongoing Projects</a>
      <a href="#">Purchase Service</a>

      <div class="separator"></div>

      <a href="#">Employment</a>
      <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="Main">

  </div>

  <div class="Footer">

  </div>
</Body>

</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using **absolute position** on the navigation so you need to add padding to main content in order to be able to add content without going under the navigation. You have also a useless element to make the separation between both parts of the navigation. Instead you can simply use `margin-left:auto`.

You are also missing units in the height/width of the image :

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div.Navigation {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #001a33;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}

div.Navigation>a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding:0 10px;
}

div.Navigation>a:nth-child(4) {
  margin-left: auto;
}

div.Navigation a img {
  height: 22.1px;
  width: 44px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div.Navigation a:visited,
div.Navigation a:active,
div.Navigation a:link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div.Navigation a:hover {
  background-color: #000d1a;
}

.Main {
  padding-top:55px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Header">
  <div class="Navigation">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/" /></a>
    <a href="#">Ongoing Projects</a>
    <a href="#">Purchase Service</a>
    <a href="#">Employment</a>
    <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="Main">
  <p>Content</p>
</div>

<div class="Footer">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance in terms of fixing the DOM. As I'm learning as I go but, the issue as to where when you hover over the home icon / image. It doesn't cover the whole entire 50 and instead only changes the background-color of the height of the icon (22.1)

Comment: @IsaacOdeyale i didn't get you, you want the image to scale on hover ?

Comment: Not that I want it to scale but, if you hover the mouse over each item on the Navigation Bar. It highlghts it perfectly but with the mouse it doesn't do that.

Comment: @IsaacOdeyale sorry i still didn't get the issue ... are you able to show a screenshot so i better understand

Comment: @IsaacOdeyale ok i see, so it's working fine here ? but not on your site .. maybe you have more CSS that you didn't add here ?